# Image size in local HTML file and inside jsFiddle/SO snippets

Tags: html, css

Here is very simple markup:

```
<style>
img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
</style>

<section>
    <figure>
        <img src="image.png">
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

Copy it to the local "test.html" file and launch. Here is what you will see:

[image]

Now, the same code launched in jsFiddle and as Stack Overflow snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/et8qud5r/:

[image]

```css
img {
    width: 100%;
    border: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<section>
    <figure>
        <img src="image.png">
        <figcaption>Caption</figcaption>
    </figure>
</section>
```

Screenshot from the snippet: (Looks identically to jSFiddle)

[image]

So, why this markup looks different between local HTML file (the image placeholder is scaled to full screen) and jsFiddle/SO (the image placeholder is scaled to the smallest possible size).

Comment: am pretty sure in your local file you are not adding head, body, doctype, etc ..right? so becarefull about quirks mode

Comment: @TemaniAfif Yeah, you are correct. `<!DOCTYPE html>` solves the issue.

Comment: read the second answer in the duplicate

Comment: @TemaniAfif Excellent, very useful.